# Visual Studio 2010 solution file character set differences?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

So I notice that you can save solution files in UTF-8, Unicode or ANSI. Does anyone have any information on the pros or cons of using each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious ones:

- ANSI is 8 bits and can only hold a limited amount of characters
- UTF-8 is a variable number of bits and supports the full range
- Unicode is UTF-16 (2 bytes) and supports the full range

So, if you are using characters not in ANSI in your solution file (folder names etc), they will get garbled.

The other considerations are file sizes that result from how many bits each character is stored as.

Comment: Ooops... that was an accidental down vote. Fixed! (should I add "accident" as a possible reason for DVs in my meta faq post? hehe)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Slip of the mouse?

Comment: hehe... I'm on mobile; "fat finger syndrome" (even if I have dainty fingers), then hit back before I realized my error! oop!